# Hebbian rule doesn't get to a fixpoint

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matrices, fixed-point

I'm trying to implement an Hopfield Network for pictures of 32x32 bits either 1 or -1;

I have these 3 pictures and I transform each of them in a vector of 1024 elements.
Then I take the 3 vectors and I build a matrix M:

```
U = [v1 v2 v3]
```

So I compute:

```
M = (U*U')/1024
```

where M is a matrix of 1024*1024 elements and I set the diagonal to 0.
in order to get the correlation matrix scaled by 1024 (Hebbian rule).

Now, theoretically each vector v should be a fixpoint. So I compute M*v. I take the sign and I compare with v. The problem is that they are different, so v is not a fixpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try working this out on paper (without computation). Should it work when you take only one vector? When you take two vectors?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have tried this with some small example and it works. Are my examples just lucky?

Comment: Try proving the general case, starting with one vector and moving to two and then three. See if it really works.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I can understand that the property doesn't hold in general because, otherwise, it would have worked in this case also. What I would like to know is:
should I do some preprocessing to the vectors in order to make this property holding?

Should I use smth else instead? Some paper that I can read about what could I use to make the vector a fixpoint?

Comment: I'm guessing that most of the time, the vector are approximate fixed points. Textbooks or the original paper should help.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what I can read in the textbook is that to make the net working that property (fixpoint) must hold for each training pattern, in order to reconstruct a distorted version of it. The point is that in the algorithm it just says tu build M in that way (assuming it would work).
That's why I'm asking for some help

Comment: You're probably expecting too much. The vectors should be *approximate* fixpoints.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/77974/755, https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/3650/1794, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45117881/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.